# What are the dangers of client side authorization?

Tags: client-side, authorization

What are the dangers of client side authorization? Where client side authorization should and should not be used?

Comment: care to expand on what you mean by client side authentication?

Answer (score 2):

The server controls the important resources.  If the server cannot enforce access control then you have built a system without access control.